# eclipse does not add classpath to manifest file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have some dependencies that I need to specify in the manifest. So I created a manifest file manually and when doing that I exported my selected files and do next >> next and then choose "use existing manifest from file". this is the manifest I have locally:

```
  Manifest-Version: 1.0
  Main-Class: com.placeholder.ProcessServer
  Class-Path: . ProcessServer_lib/commons-net-3.3.jar ProcessServer_lib/
  com.ibm.mq.headers.jar ProcessServer_lib/db2jcc.jar ProcessServer_lib
  /db2jcc_license_cu.jar ProcessServer_lib/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar Pro
  cessServer_lib/com.ibm.mq.jar ProcessServer_lib/com.ibm.mq.commonserv
  ices.jar ProcessServer_lib/connector.jar ProcessServer_lib/com.ibm.mq
  .jmqi.jar ProcessServer_lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

I placed the jar in my unix box and invoke it via a shell script using -jar however it gives me a  `classdef not found exception`. Upon seeing the jar generated via decomplier/zip utility I can see the manifest only contains the main-Class line not the class-path. 
While exporting the jar should I unselect the buildpath that comes in the right hand box selection ?
I'm doing these deployment works for the first time, but I have tried for 1 day using `-cp` to specify jar folder and main class but I still haven't found a way. Could somebody help me or give me advice?

p.s. I don't use maven/ant so no need to advice me on that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in Eclipse where it won't export the last line of your manifest if you don't leave a trailing newline.

Answer (score -1):

Export your project using the export to `runnable jar` of Eclipse and remeber to choose between these :

- Extract required libraries into generated JAR : to inflate the referenced jar files and copy the classes into the generated jar
- Package required libraries into generated JAR : to copy the referenced jar files as is into the generated jar
- Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR

See [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-export-runnable-jar.htm)

Comment: You really just copied the docs AND put a link to them in your answer?

Comment: I answered the question by recommending the export to runnable jar then added a link to the documentation in case he needs more details (can't see what is wrong with it ...)